# MVC3 Call controller method from Pop up window

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have problem to call the method from view to controller.

**SendVotingPanel.cshtml**

```
@model EmailTemplete.Models.SendVotingEmail

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "SendVotingPanel";
}
 <h2>SendVotingPanel</h2>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"` src="/resources/demos/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function Send() {
        $(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog();
        });
    };
</script>

<input type="button" value="submit" id="openpopup" onclick="Send();"/>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <div style="display:none" id="dialog">

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactEmail)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactEmail)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactEmail)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subject)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
        </div>
                   <br />
         <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        </p>
</div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult SendVotingPanel()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendVotingPanel(Models.SendVotingEmail model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

When I click on **openpopup** button then one pop up window was displayed. When I fill all textbox with some data and click on button then I am not able to call method **SendVotingPanel**. 
Is there any change in my code is remaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <div style="display:none" id="dialog">
       ...
   </div>
}
```

To:

```
<div style="display:none" id="dialog">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
       ...
    }
</div>
```